# APScheduler run async function in Tornado Python

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, tornado, apscheduler

I am trying to develop a small app which will gather weather data from an API. I have used APScheduler to execute the function every x minutes. I use Python Tornado framework.

The error I am getting is:

```
INFO     Job "GetWeather (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-03-28 11:40:58 CET)" executed successfully
ERROR    Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x0335C978>, <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x03374430>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 568, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread
```

Which I think is coming from the Coroutine from GetWeather() as, if I remove all asycn features from it, it works.

I am using Motor to read needed coordinates and pass them through the API and store weather data in MongoDB.

```
import os.path, logging
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import define, options
from apscheduler.schedulers.tornado import TornadoScheduler
import motor

client = motor.MotorClient()
db = client['apitest']

console_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("debug", default=False, help="run in debug mode")

class MainRequest (tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello")

scheduler = TornadoScheduler()

class ScheduledTasks(object):
    def get(self):
        print("This is the scheduler");

def AddJobs():
    scheduler.add_job(GetWeather, 'interval', minutes=1)

def StartScheduler():
    scheduler.start();

def StopScheduler():
    scheduler.stop();

class Weather(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("This is the Weather Robot!")
        GetWeather()

@gen.coroutine
def GetWeather():
    '''
    Getting city weather from forecast.io API
    '''
    console_log.debug('Start: weather robot')    
    cursor = FindCities()

    while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
        city = cursor.next_object()
        lat = str(city["lat"])
        lon = str(city["lon"])     
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("https://api.forecast.io/forecast/3925d0668cf520768ca855951f1097cd/%s,%s" %(lat, lon))

        if response.error:
            print ("Error:", response.error)
            # Store all cities with errors in order to save them in the log file
        else:         
            json = tornado.escape.json_decode(response.body)
            temperature =  json["currently"]["temperature"]
            summary = json["currently"]["summary"]
            db.cities.update({'_id': city["_id"]}, {'$set': {'temperature': temperature, 'summary': summary}})

    console_log.debug('End: weather robot')
    return

def FindCities():
    '''
    cities = [{
                "_id" : ObjectId("55165d07258058ee8dca2172"),
                "name" : "London",
                "country" : "United Kingdom",
                "lat" : 51.507351,
                "lon" : -0.127758
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("55165d07258058ee8dca2173"),
                "name" : "Barcelona",
                "country" : "Spain",
                "lat" : 41.385064,
                "lon" : 2.173403
            }      
    '''
    cities = db.cities.find().sort([('_id', -1)])
    return cities

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    app = tornado.web.Application(
            [
                (r'/robots/weather', Weather),
                (r'/', MainRequest)
            ],
            cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
            login_url="/auth/login",
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            xsrf_cookies=True,
            debug=options.debug,
        )
    app.listen(options.port)
    AddJobs()
    StartScheduler()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? As I see in APScheduler code, TornadoScheduler() runs in Tornado IOLoop... (https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/a34075b0037dba46735bae67f598ec6133003ef1/apscheduler/schedulers/tornado.py?at=master)

Oh! I forgot to say that the idea is to be able to execute the task via APScheduler or manually both.

Many thanks!

Comment: Investigating more I belive the issue is with the simulatious use of Motor and APScheduler but I don't know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TornadoScheduler runs scheduled tasks in a thread pool. Your specific task, however, uses the IOLoop and so expects to be run in the same thread. To fix this, you can use the add_callback() method of the tornado IOLoop to schedule a task to be run in the IOLoop's thread as soon as possible.

Like so:

```
def your_scheduled_task():
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(your_real_task_function)
```

or even better:

```
scheduler.add_job(IOLoop.instance().add_callback, 'interval', minutes=1, args=[GetWeather])
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I am not sure how to implement the solution you proposed. I don't want to sound opportunist but could you provide an example? I have been trying sevelar things but I did not get anything working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like TornadoScheduler, even though it integrates with the IOLoop, it [still runs operations on a thread pool](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/a34075b0037dba46735bae67f598ec6133003ef1/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py?at=master#cl-628):

```
def _create_default_executor(self):
    """Creates a default executor store, specific to the particular scheduler type."""
    return ThreadPoolExecutor()
```

Motor doesn't like running on multiple threads in the same process--I only test use cases where Motor is used on the main thread.

I think you should either use a Tornado PeriodicCallback instead of APScheduler, or you should use PyMongo with APScheduler (so PyMongo is running on background threads) instead of Motor.

Comment: If no advanced scheduler features are used, PeriodicCallback would indeed be simpler.

Comment: Thank you both! I only need to schedule some tasks to be run during midnight this is why I wanted to include APScheduler. I want the tasks to be executed on a particular time.