# Python script suddenly fails to compile with "expected an indent block"

Tags: python

This script has been working fine, however now when I go to execute it, it fails to compile with:

```
  File "/Users/camerongordon/Desktop/Python Scripts/hello.py", line 12
    def ConnectToDatabase(): 
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here is the script:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado import gen 
from tornado.options import define, options 
from apscheduler.schedulers.tornado import TornadoScheduler
from torndb import Connection

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

def ConnectToDatabase(): 
   db = Connection("127.0.0.1", 'helloworld', user='root', password='')
   return db

application = tornado.web.Application
([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

def ProcessQueue:

def main(): 
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316173/apscheduler-run-async-function-in-tornado-python
    # https://github.com/teriyakichild/example-scheduler/blob/master/example_scheduler/__init__.py

    application.listen(8888)

    db = ConnectToDatabase() 

    scheduler = TornadoScheduler()

    scheduler.add_job(ProcessQueue, 'interval', name='tick-interval-3-seconds', seconds=4, timezone='America/Chicago')

    scheduler.start()

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

What is going on? Everything looks syntactically correct and indented properly.

Comment: You are missing the definition of `get` method of `MainHandler` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

def ConnectToDatabase(): 
   db = Connection("127.0.0.1", 'helloworld', user='root', password='')
   return db
```

Your `def get(self):` calls for a method body to come; if you add `pass`, things will work. You probably, by accident, omitted or deleted some code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pass

def ConnectToDatabase(): 
   db = Connection("127.0.0.1", 'helloworld', user='root', password='')
   return db
```

Also, your indents are unequal -- that's not a good sign. Use a proper editor.

Comment: The [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states indents should be 4 spaces. Make sure to configure a proper editor (such as Sublime Text, Notepad++, vim, emacs, etc.) for this when programming in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try highlighting your script and converting all indentation to tabs? Sublime has an option for that. Also, you def get(): doesn't have a body.